# Suppress the first exception when catching an exception in py.test and raising an error

Tags: python, exception, pytest

I have a simple `py.test` that attempts to reach a domain and fails if it can't reach it. I don't want to see the entire urllib stack trace generated.

For example:

```
import py.test
import requests
import sys

def test_failure():
    url = 'https://www.nosuchdomain.com'
    try:
        r = requests.post(url=url, timeout=1)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Can't reach "+url,file=sys.stdout)
        assert False
```

But the output I get is too long!

```
[Dance ~/tests 15:21:57]$ py.test connect_test.py
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/simsong/tests, inifile:
collected 1 items

connect_test.py F

============================================ FAILURES =============================================
__________________________________________ test_failure ___________________________________________

self = <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10d672c50>

    def _new_conn(self):
        """ Establish a socket connection and set nodelay settings on it.

            :return: New socket connection.
            """
        extra_kw = {}
        if self.source_address:
            extra_kw['source_address'] = self.source_address

        if self.socket_options:
            extra_kw['socket_options'] = self.socket_options

        try:
            conn = connection.create_connection(
>               (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py:138:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
... 1000 lines removed ...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    def test_failure():
        url = 'https://www.nosuchdomain.com'
        try:
            r = requests.post(url=url, timeout=1)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Can't reach "+url,file=sys.stdout)
>           assert False
E           assert False

connect_test.py:11: AssertionError
-------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------
Can't reach https://www.nosuchdomain.com
==================================== 1 failed in 1.63 seconds =====================================
[Dance ~/tests 15:22:01]$
```

How do I eliminate all the output I don't want?

Comment: Use `--tb` to control the traceback. E.g. `pytest --tb=short` for short tracebacks, `pytest --tb=line` for one line per error or `pytest --tb=no` for no traceback at all.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the way I raise the exception?

Comment: Well, you can refactor the test so the `assert False` is called outside the `except` clause. For example, set `failed = True` in `except`, then call `if failed: pytest.fail('cant reach url')` in the main scope of the test function.

Comment: That’s an idea. It’s gross, but it would work, I guess. If you make it an answer, I will select it.